# What does Aguero's tattoo say?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, elves

I recently noticed in a local English paper a photo of a football player being stretchered off the pitch. I instantly recognised the tattoo on his arm as Elvish but I didn't know what it said. I tried to take a photo:

[image: Aguero's tattoo]

The players name is Aguero.

What does his tattoo say?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sergio Leonel "Kun" Agüero del Castillo, who play under the shirt name Kun Aguero, as well as Fernando Torres both have their names written in the Elvish script of Tengwar. Quoting Wikipedia:

> Spanish footballer Fernando Torres has a tattoo on the inside of his left arm that reads "Fernando" in tengwar, as does his former Atletico Madrid team mate Sergio Agüero whose reads "Kun Agüero". (Fernando's tattoo uses ómatehtar, although inconsistently, with Sindarin mode for the first two vowels, and Quenya mode for the last "o"; and also contains "n+(n)d" when just "(n)d" (with a nasalisation bar) would have been sufficient.